# Best way to store large number of datarow for querying

Tags: .net, sql-server, database

Whats the best way to store a large number (several millions) of records used to create reports on? The nature of the application demands that each record that matches a search is sent to the application for processing so both the query-execution speed and the query-result transfer speed is big factors for us.

Currently our application stores records in one straight MSSQL table heavily indexed for query performance. 
Does anybody have any alternative storage ideas or is an relational database a good fit for this even though we can only store records in one table since the data is not relational in it self?

The SQL solution gives us pretty good performance but I am intrested if there are other better backend alternatives, for example is NoSQL databases a valid solution to start looking in to?

Our queries are made against a small number of columns but the results can vary in size (number of row needed for each execution depending on period and some other parameters).

Thanks in advance for helping me to get some new perspectives on this.

Since we are a .NET shop any solutions/ideas that fits good with .NET and Windows servers are a big plus for us but I am appreciating all input I can get on this.
And by solutions I mean some other backend than MSSQL or other relational-dbs?

Comment: Don't follow.  "can only store records in one column since the data is not relational in it self"  "Our queries are made against a small number of columns"   If the records are in one column how do you queries against more than 1 column?

Comment: I am really sorry, its should say "one table". The post is now edited. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

The query efficiency is based on query and the indexes

For transferring the data to the client:

- Just a straight up DataReader is very efficient
- Drapper is also fast  but I have not used it

I had a valid interpretation that the query results should be saved to be re-run
The query is only run once

```
Data
int ID iden 
varchar Value1
varchar Value2

SavedQuery
int ID iden 
varchar name 

SavedQueryResults 
int QueryID PK
int DataID PK

Select [Data].[Value1],  [Data].[Value2]
From [Data] 
Join [SavedQueryResults]
  on [SavedQueryResults].[DataID] = [Data].[ID]
 and [SavedQueryResults].[QueryID] = x
```

With the PK on SavedQueryResults this should result in an index seek and cannot do better than that.

When you create the SavedQueryResults use order by DataID in the insert to keep fragmentation down

Comment: Ok, that sound like a good solution, but in my case when a report is made for a set of data the processed result of the data is saved in the application (as an aggregated result) so the same query is almost never executed more then once. 
Otherwise I think it would have been a good solution.

But do I understand you correct that to store the data in a mssql table is an "valid" solution for my case, even though there are ways to speed up performace of queries with solutions like the one you described?

Comment: You should put that in the question.  Run once is a whole different optimization.  I read application stores "them" as the report.

Comment: Valid point, I have edit the question to be more specific about what i meant. 
But do you think that the use of one table as the storage is a good starting point and optimize from that or are there better solutions that could be used?
And by solutions i mean some other backend than MSSQL or other relational-dbs?

Comment: If you don't have relation data then splitting it artificially won't help.  You should post the table definition and some common queries.  But also need to consider the speed to download.  .NET has great SQL download tools that needs to be considered.

Comment: What do you mean by SQL Download tools? I am not familiar with that term but it sounds intresting!

Comment: Like SQLdatareader and Drapper.  Fast communication to / from MSSQL from .NET.

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarifying. We use a SQLDataReader right now. But I am going to look into Drapper a bit to see if it could add some value to us. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you rather have a couple of report tables, updated with triggers, it would be a lot more efficient. The same as view models in the CQRS world.

Comment: Can you elaborate on you answer a little bit? Why would that be a better solution for this case, I dont understand the benefit?

Comment: How many tables do you have to join in order to get the reports? And depending on the table lock you're using, when executing those queries you might be well bringring the whole systems performance down. What if two clients request the same report? View models work as caching tables that have the exact data the report needs, so if the client request it, it is just there straight away.

Comment: There is only on table where all the data for the report is located. And each report (query) is almost always only executed once so I dont think that a "caching" approach is right for us. 
Since in our case a record never changes once its in the table and unrepetable reads etc. is not an issue in our application we dont need to utilize any row or table looks when reading (READ UNCOMMITTED).